# Hosting static aboutus page on S3 bucket and linking to godaddy

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, amazon-s3

I have a domain through godaddy (`www.example.com`) and it is hosted on a different server. I also have a static aboutus page that I have in an S3 bucket. How do I link my aboutus page to the main website so that it has a URL of `www.example.com/aboutus`? What changes should I make in my DNS settings?

Comment: The DNS does not work at the URL level. With both `https://www.example.com/` and `https://www.example.com/aboutus` the DNS is involved in exactly the same way, just to resolve `www.example.com` to some IP addresses. It is then the webserver at this IP address that has to generate the content based on the full URL. So it is a matter of configuring your webserver, maybe with a redirect or a proxy, to fetch the specific page from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use DNS to point different pages on the same host name at different servers.  All the documents on `www.example.com` have to be served from the same server.   DNS can only point `www.example.com` to one IP address.  It can't be split up based on pages.

There are however, some things you can do instead.

### Use a subdomain

If you want to host some content on a separate server such as an S3 bucket, you could create a subdomain for that separate server.  Subdomains are separate host names for DNS.  You can point subdomains to different host names using DNS.

For example you could create the subdomain `s3.example.com` and point it to the S3 bucket.   Then the URL of your "about us" page would be `http://s3.example.com/aboutus`.

If the "about us" page were the only thing in the S3 bucket, you could name the file `index.html` in the S3 bucket and point the subdomain `about-us.example.com` to the S3 bucket.   Then the URL for the page would be `http://about-us.example.com/`.

### Use a reverse proxy

Your main web server could run a reverse proxy to dynamically fetch documents from the S3 bucket and re-serve them itself.   It is very common to use a reverse proxy to assign paths on the main domain to content run on different servers or different port numbers.

A reverse proxy is a great solution when the servers are on the same local network.   When the two servers are geographically distant, using a reverse proxy can make those requests significantly slower.

For example if your main server is running Apache with `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy` enabled, you could use this configuration to reverse proxy the page:

```
RewriteRule ^/?about-us http://s3.example.us-west.amazonaws.com/about-us [P]
```

Then the URL of the page would be `http://www.example.com/about-us`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check out [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) for hosting static sites because they have a generous free tier and static sites are their primary focus.

**In AWS Console**

1. Create a bucket
2. Name a bucket to be your domain name for easy setup.
3. Go to bucket properties
4. Go to edit bucket policy
5. In text editor, edit a resource key with your domain name after `::`
6. Go to static web hosting
7. Enable a web hosting option
8. There is an endpoint link which is used to point your bucket to the domain

**In GoDaddy Console**

1. Go to manage DNS
2. Point **CNAME** of `www` to endpoint you received from the AWS console

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzNlwGaccs4

Comment: The OP said he already has a website on a server, but just only one page is in a S3 bucket. So the question is not just how to host a whole website in an S3 bucket.